# How to avoid ^C getting printed after handling KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface

This morning I decided to handle keyboard interrupt in my server program and exit gracefully. I know how to do it, but my finicky self didn't find it graceful enough that `^C` still gets printed. How do I avoid `^C` getting printed?

```
import sys
from time import sleep
try:
  sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt, ke:
  sys.exit(0)
```

Press Ctrl+C to get out of above program and see `^C` getting printed. Is there some `sys.stdout` or `sys.stdin` magic I can use?

Comment: You could try using something in the [`curses` package](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html), but I don't think it's trivial (if it's possible at all).

Comment: I see ^C printed out on bash and csh, its either consistent across shells or something at a lower (kernel) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, at least in Linux

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import termios
import copy
from time import sleep

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
new = copy.deepcopy(old)
new[3] = new[3] & ~termios.ECHO

try:
  termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)
  sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt, ke:
  pass
finally:
  termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
  sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 9):

It's your shell doing that, python has nothing to do with it.

If you put the following line into `~/.inputrc`, it will suppress that behavior:

```
set echo-control-characters off
```

Of course, I'm assuming you're using bash which may not be the case.

Answer (score 8):

```
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\r  "
```

Comment: Thanks.  Quickest and cleanest solution +1. I would advice that you elaborate your example to be more comprehensible and maybe explain what **`\r`** does

Comment: Even cleaner: `sys.stderr.write("\r")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way of doing this, but I fix that problem by printing two `\b` (backspace escape sequence) and then a space or a series of characters. This might work fine

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Your main code goes here
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\b\bProgram Ended")
```